# Unable to resolve "react" from "App.js" (Expo CLI)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I recently updated Expo SDK to 37 (my previous version was 33). Since the update, I’m unable to open the app and it appears that a lot of modules aren’t resolved (while they do exists in my project file). I’ve cleared my cache, deleted Node-modules folder and re-installed Expo. Nothing works. I still get the following error: "Unable to resolve “react” from “App.js”

Hope someone can help me out with this! Thanks in advance

Here’s my code in App.js:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import AppNavigator from "./navigator/AppNavigator";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";


console.disableYellowBox = true;


initialState.recipies = shuffleArray(initialState.recipies);
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

store.subscribe(() => {
  // console.log("store changed", store.getState().recipies);
});

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppNavigator />
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to uninstall expo app on your simulator (`Hardware` and `Erase all Content` : will delete everything on your Simulator) to have the latest version of the expo app.

Comment: I've tried that. Didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: Did you try to run `expo update` after  your `npm update` ?

Comment: Just tried, getting this message: `Unable to resolve "react" from "node_modules/expo/build/launch/withExpoRoot.js"`, when dismissing that message I receive the error above again.

Comment: Hmm, no more idea about this one :/ just open an issue on `Expo` repo then I guess

Comment: yea, I've opened an issue and hope someone can help me. Thanks for replying! Much appreciated :)

Comment: UPDATE: I've managed to solve this issue myself. React navigation turned out to be outdated and not working. I've updated all related components and syntax and everything worked fine after that! Rookie mistake I guess ;).